# change user login status from admin panel in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, sql-update

I am working on a system which user can register and login and see there own profile & have a Main Admin who can see and modify the user login STATUS. If admin change the user status then user can't login to his account. (block User). Predefined user status is "Y" and if admin want to restrict that user to login admin can change the status to "N" so user can't login.

i am learning php and i don't get the right technique  to do that.

**Below is the code where I show the user table and wan to change the status.**

```
<table border="1" class="pricing-table-wrapper col-sm-4">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>password</th>
        <th>first_name</th>
        <th>last_name</th>
        <th>city</th>
        <th>signup_date</th>
        <th>ac_number</th>

        <th>bank_name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Action</th>


    </tr>
    <?php
    //We get the IDs, usernames and emails of users
    $req = mysqli_query($conn, 'select id, username, email, password, first_name, last_name, city, signup_date, ac_number, bank_name, status from users');
    while($dnn = mysqli_fetch_array($req))
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="left"><?php echo $dnn['id']; ?></td>
        <td class="left"><?php echo htmlentities($dnn['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
        <td class="left"><?php echo htmlentities($dnn['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
        <td class="left"><?php echo htmlentities($dnn['password'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
        <td class="left"><?php echo htmlentities($dnn['first_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
        <td class="left"><?php echo htmlentities($dnn['last_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
        <td class="left"><?php echo htmlentities($dnn['city'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
        <td class="left"><?php echo htmlentities($dnn['signup_date'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
        <td class="left"><?php echo htmlentities($dnn['ac_number'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
        <td class="left"><?php echo htmlentities($dnn['bank_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>


        <td class="left"><?php echo htmlentities($dnn['status'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
        <td class="left">CHANGE USER STATUS</td>




           <?php
         }
      ?>

    </tr>

    </table>
```

THE CODE WHICH I TRIED

```
 <td>

        <a href='changestatus.php?id=<?=$dnn['id']?>'>

            <img src="a6block.jpg" width="50px" >


        </a>


        <?php 

        include('config.php');

        if(isset($_GET['id']))
        {

        // lookup the current status of user 'id'

        // Update DB with the new status    

        $sql_query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$_GET['id'];
            $result_set=mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);
            $fetched_row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);


             $sql_query = "UPDATE users SET status='N' WHERE id=".$_GET['id'];
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);



        }
        header("Location: users.php");

        exit;
        // redirect back to the previous page


        ?>
```

?>

THIS IS MAY BE A WRONG TECHNIQUE SO WHAT CAN I DO?

Comment: on click on change status, fire a call to php file and change the status

Comment: but i also want to change the user status in database @Niranjan N Raju  so user can't get logged in

Comment: while login check for the status.

Comment: are you familiar with ajax??

Comment: use an update query for the table .... like "UPDATE users SET status = N WHERE id = 'get_the_user_id_here' "

Comment: this is have two login part one is for user and second is for admin. when user login then user status is "Y" and if the Main Admin want to BLOCK the user the admin can change the status form his admin panel to "N". so user get block.

Comment: Posting code that works doesn't help. Post the update code that doesn't work as intended. Read the help on how to post a [mcve].

Comment: @Gerald Schneider  sir i tried to take the status in the form and then update it but it can't working.

Comment: @ankitsuthar well post what you tried, otherwise nobody can tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider  I DONE IT SIR,,   i am learning php so i don't know the right technique.

Comment: You are mixing `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables. What method do you have defined in your `<form>` definition?

Comment: @Gerald Schneider you reduce my reputation sir..    don't do that. if you don't want to answer than it's ok but don't do that.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider  i am trying to learn by using different example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a link to a new PHP page and pass the ID of the user..

```
<td class="left">
    <a href="changestatus.php?id=<?=$dnn['id']?>">
        <?php echo htmlentities($dnn['status'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
    </a>
</td>
```

Then in **changestatus.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){

    // lookup the current status of user 'id'

    // Update DB with the new status    

}
// redirect back to the previous page
header("Location: /previouspage.php");
exit;
```

Or.. .to prevent a page reload, you could always use AJAX..

Comment: can you help me to add AJAX so i prevent the page reloding.

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, but for the AJAX method you are going to have to do something like this..

```
<td class="left">
    <a href="#" class='changeStatus' id='<?php echo $dnn['id'] ?>'>
        <?php echo htmlentities($dnn['status'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
    </a>
</td>
```

**In your JS file...**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.changeStatus').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'changestatus.php',
            data: this,
        })
        .done(function() {
            //success
        })
        .fail(function() {
            //failure
        });
    });
 });
```

*Don't forget.. ..that AJAX will change the DB value, but the display will still show the original value.  So you will have to update the display in the 'success' part of the AJAX call.*